# 2d Game Sprite's Position goes to -2147483648 in X and Y axis when it reaches a point

Tags: c++, vector, artificial-intelligence, sprite

So I'm starting with a really basic AI which I will expand later on but this problem is giving me a headache. The enemy is supposed to go to the top middle of the screen if the player is in the bottom, and go to the bottom middle if the player is at the top. It should then stay there while shooting at the player until destroyed. Enemies avoid collisions with each other in a jerky way but that's not really related. Here's the code:

```
for (n = 0; n < upgrades.size(); n++)
    {
        for (inner = 0; inner < upgrades.size(); inner++)       
        {
            if (n != inner && upgrades[n]->HitTest(upgrades[inner])) 
            {
                upgradeCollide = true;
                if (upgrades[n]->GetX() < upgrades[inner]->GetX())  upgrades[n]->SetPosition(upgrades[n]->GetX() - 10, upgrades[n]->GetY());
                else if (upgrades[n]->GetX() > upgrades[inner]->GetX()) upgrades[n]->SetPosition(upgrades[n]->GetX() + 10, upgrades[n]->GetY());
                else if (upgrades[n]->GetY() < upgrades[inner]->GetY()) upgrades[n]->SetPosition(upgrades[n]->GetX(), upgrades[n]->GetY() - 10);
                else if (upgrades[n]->GetY() > upgrades[inner]->GetY()) upgrades[n]->SetPosition(upgrades[n]->GetX(), upgrades[n]->GetY() + 10);
                upgradeCollide = false;
            }
        }
        upgradeVX = 400 - upgrades[n]->GetX();
        if (player.GetY() >= 300) upgradeVY = 150 -  upgrades[n]->GetY();
        else if (player.GetY() < 300)  upgradeVY = 450 -  upgrades[n]->GetY();
        //Above 3 lines is the enemy seeking the position
        upgradeLength = sqrt(upgradeVX * upgradeVX + upgradeVY * upgradeVY);
        upgradeVX = upgradeVX / upgradeLength * 100;
        upgradeVY = upgradeVY / upgradeLength * 100;
        //Above is normalization of the velocity vector (VX, VY)
        enemy_rotation = atan2(upgrades[n]->GetY() - player.GetY(), upgrades[n]->GetX() - player.GetX()) * (180/3.14159);
        upgrades[n]->SetRotation(enemy_rotation-90);
        if (!upgradeCollide) upgrades[n]->SetVelocity(upgradeVX, upgradeVY);
}
```

So it should be seeking two different points depending on where the player is. Strange thing is that it works just fine if I don't normalize the velocity vector, but of course it must be normalized otherwise it would look weird and be unfair.

Keep in mind when an enemy reaches the target and collides because another enemy is already there, it will just push it to the left or right and make enough space (That is only if I don't normalize because otherwise they travel a million pixels - with normalization)

So does anyone know why they are traveling an insane amount of pixels when they hit one of the two targets? I just want them to stop at the target and shoot the player.

Comment: I think you are overflowing an integer value somewhere. Run it in a debugger.

Comment: It seems that upgradeLength is reaching ridiculous values. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel like having a vector of upgradeLength and giving each instance of an enemy their own upgradeLength will fix it. I'll give that a go.